# New Content type is not listing in Add Content in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, nodes

When create custom content type through UI or programmatically in Drupal 7, there is no link is listed in the **Content > Add content**.

I was creating the content types without any trouble, but now it is created(succes message is showing) when I check them in the **node_type** table but not lising in the *admin/structure/types*.

But no content type is listing(not any links showing) in the **Content > Add content**, or **Structure > Content type** administration menu.

Here is the code that allows users to access node pages:

```
/*
 * Allow users to view the contents
 */
function mymodule_node_access_records($node){
    $grants = array();
    $grants[] = array(
        'realm' => 'example_realm',
        'gid' => 123,
        'grant_view' => 1,


  'grant_update' => 0,
    'grant_delete' => 0,
    'priority' => 0,
);
return $grants;
}


/**
 * Implements hook_node_grants().
 */
function mymodule_node_grants($account, $op){
    $grants = array();
    if ($op == 'view') {
        $grants['example_realm'] = array(
            123,
        );
    }
    return $grants;
}
```

Then I rebuild permissions using **Content Access** module.

Comment: Iv'e only had this issue right after I create one and a page refresh fixes it. Could it be perms perhaps?

Comment: have you emptied the cache ?

Comment: I am hanging with this for 5hrs(min). It would not be that easy to count the cache operations. @rtome: Thank you for your comment anyway.

Comment: are you using any cache other than default core cache? Say [Authcache](http://drupal.org/project/authcache) or [Memcache](http://drupal.org/project/memcache).

Comment: also manually check this path, is it a 404? 403? 500? yourdomain.com/node/add/MACHINE_NAME where MACHINE_NAME is the machine name (doh!) of the node type you created.

Answer (score 2):

1. Check the permission for node creation of that type in **admin/people/permissions**
2. Clear all caches and retry and it should be OK

Comment: May be you are getting to the point. But how is it possible to -"check the permission for node creation of that type", when I am going to create a new type?

Comment: @usermesam0023 check the permission of the one you already created but has disappeared. It's listed in the permissions list as 'create new node of type XYZ'.

Comment: Also, try to access directly this link **node/add/your-new-type**

Comment: @nabil: I have posted this question after I tried all these possibilities. When I go this path: I get the same 'Add Content' form.

Comment: Now I am running the site with the single 'Administrator'(allowed all permissions) and other users(anonymous). I have allowed these anonymous users to access all my node contents. Now I am going to add this code to my question.

Comment: You didn't mention before that you are using the **content access** module.
Ok, try disabling this module, and rebuild permissions in this page : **admin/reports/status/rebuild**, then try accessing the **node/add/content-type**