# I Can't add node of a custom content type

Tags: nodes

I have to add a new content type to my site for a new feature i'm asked. I already added two of them before (very early in the building of the site, in fact) and it worked well but this time, when i want to add a new node, my new content type doesn't appear in the list of content types (node/add).

It appears in the admin/structure/types page but not in the node/add.

I cleared the cache and rebuild permissions but nothing happened.

I also tried to create a very basic new content type but it didn't appear either.

An earlier exchange on this forum showed it wasn't likely to be the taxonomy access control module.

If I do a clean install of drupal and create a new content type, it works but on my site, i can't do it so i don't think it is because i forgot some step.

May it be because of some problem with a third party module ?

I don't think i have installed very exotic ones but i have some (CKEditor, Taxonomy access control, Piwik Web Analytics... )

I'm turning mad so if someone has some clue, it may really help.

Thank you

Comment: I guess, you would have checked this. But you can recheck at permission for adding content at admin/people/permission/Node.

Comment: I rechecked but permissions were OK

Comment: Try the following option, Go to structure>menus>navigation>list links, Then check under the Add Content option your newly created content is appearing there and it is enabled. Why because the *Add Content* menu is there, hence good to check there.

Comment: if you can see your content type link under `Add content`, if it is enabled, you can disable->save configuration and again re-enabled and clear cache. This should work. Other think you can try is remove the underscore from your machine-readable name, e.g. if you content type is Article New, so by default drupal will give machine-readable name article_new, so change the MR name like articlenew.

Comment: Thank you, I tried what you say but I can't see any add content option under structure>menus>navigation>list links. Instead, I can see my new content type but not the others. I also tried to remove the underscore from my machine name but it didn't change anything. I also tried to go to the good add content page by writing the url (http//.../node/add/newcontenttype). This didn't work with the underscore but now works without it so i can put a menu link pointing directly to this content type.

Comment: I still can't reach my new content type in the "add content" page but at least, i can do it through a custom menu link (which is, in fact, the best way to do it for my purpose). So, if you have further clue for me to understand how to customize the "add content" page, let me know but this is no more a real problem.

Comment: No, it is not a sure answer hence I am posting it in comment, if it will be answer I will post as a answer. Now, this issue has been experienced by several people. I am posting you a link so you can read and try [link-1](https://www.drupalgardens.com/content/new-content-type-not-appearing-add-content), [link-2](https://www.drupal.org/node/1166416), [link-3](https://www.drupal.org/node/1073994), [link-4](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/142370/new-content-type-is-not-listing-in-add-content-in-drupal-7). Various people have solved this issue with different solutions.

Comment: Link-1 is the one i missed (2 also, 3 and 4 seems to concentrate on permissions). I found the "add content" menu (which is under "redaction" in my site - I now remind having changed that). So Everything is now ok. Thanks very much. Why trying to solve this particular problem, I've learned valuable things about the drupal organisation

Comment: So, it was just a menu displacement issue, right? Otherwise it is working fine?

Comment: If solved and you know how then you can answer your own question. So, in future people may solve their issue, if they have same issue like this.

Comment: It was not just a displacement issue. It was the main but I think the underscore was a problem too : with the underscore, i couldn't go on the add content page even by directly writing the url.

Comment: Is this about Drupal 5, or any release above that?

Comment: No. It's Drupal 7. But it is solved now. Thank you. It's just i have to wait for tomorrow before accepting my own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After following clues mentioned in the above comments (by [CodeNext](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/52479/codenext)), I was able to solve my problem. The issues and the solution I have compiled as below.

There were two problems.

- For some needed reason, I displaced the "add content" menu from "Navigation" to "Redaction" (a new menu). This caused the new content type not appear in the "Add content" page. By displacing the new content type in the "add content" menu, I could see my new content type in the right place.
- I had a underscore in the content type machine name. Because of this, i couldn't navigate to the node/add/newcontenttype page (I reached the node/add page). By removing it (the underscore), everything goes now the right way.